# GNU/Linux flock command: how to atomically take several locks

Tags: linux, gnu

I have several commands that I would like to run in parallel, but only if there are no conflicts in the resources they access. So I decided to use `flock`. Each command must take one exclusive (write) lock and several shared (read) locks. As `flock` does not support multiple locks, I naively thought that something like:

```
flock -x a flock -s b flock -s c ... <command>
```

would work. I quickly discovered that there are race conditions with this approach, due to the fact that the set of locks is not atomic. When launching:

```
flock -x a flock -s b <command1> &
flock -x b flock -s a <command2> &
```

it can be that the two exclusive locks are taken simultaneously and the two commands enter a deadlock because they cannot take their shared locks.

Is there a workaround? Are they other locking utilities that support multiple locks in an atomic way? Or should I create my own one that tries to takes the locks, releases them all after a timeout if it fails, and tries again after a random delay? Or something similar?

**Update** apparently, sorting the locks by name solves the issue:

```
flock -x a flock -s b <command1> &
flock -s a flock -x b <command2> &
```

but how robust is this? Will it avoid deadlocks in all situations with any number of commands, number of locks, lock names and sets of locks per command (still with the constraint that there is exactly one exclusive lock per command)?

Comment: It looks to me `<command1>` and `<command2>` from your examples will never run in parallel. A shared lock will prevent exclusive lock on the same file; an exclusive lock will prevent any lock on the same file. So you can just run these commands in sequence. Make sure your actual problem is not flawed in the same way, otherwise the whole "parallel" idea is pointless. If there's exactly one exclusive lock per command then `<commandA>` may run in parallel with `<commandB>` if `A` doesn't lock `B`'s exclusive file at all and `B` doesn't lock `A`'s exclusive file at all.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am not sure I understand your first comment. I know that, in my examples, the commands I show will not run in parallel. In the first example because there is a deadlock and in the second because reordering the locks prevented the deadlock by forcing a sequential execution. They were just examples of cases where things go wrong. Did I miss something?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you know the examples never benefit from parallel execution. If the actual problem was similarly flawed (every command locks *every* crucial file) you could run everything in sequence and (probably) without `flock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [*dining philosophers problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem). By sorting the locks you implement [*resource hierarchy solution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Resource_hierarchy_solution).

> While the resource hierarchy solution avoids deadlocks, it is not always practical, especially when the list of required resources is not completely known in advance.

It looks like it is robust if only you can sort your resources and stick to it.

---

A workaround may be not to let `flock` wait indefinitely, then add some logic to detect cases when it exited because it couldn't lock a file and e.g. repeat the whole task after some random time.

In [`man flock`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) one can see:

> `-n`, `--nb`, `--nonblock`
>   Fail (with an exit code of `1`) rather than wait if the lock cannot be immediately acquired.
>
> `-w`, `--wait`, `--timeout seconds`
>   Fail (with an exit code of `1`) if the lock cannot be acquired within seconds seconds. Decimal fractional values are allowed.

The problem is: a possible exit code of `1` can come from any `flock` or from the underlying command. If your `flock` supports `-E` to specify a custom exit code -- use it maybe.

This is a simple example of the approach:

```
while ! flock -n -x file <command> ; do sleep $(($RANDOM%5)) ; done
```

You can use multiple `flock`-s. If any of them cannot lock the file, all locks are released and the entire line waits at `sleep`, not at `flock`; at this time it won't block another similar line executed in parallel.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is the solution I was suggesting in my question. But I was expecting something better, if it exists.

Comment: You are right, Kamil, it looks like the resource hierarchy solution of the dining philosophers problem... Except for the shared locks and unique exclusive lock per job. What I'd like to know is whether it changes something or not.

Answer (score 2):

When I was involved in real-time programming, I always abhorred delay / retry solutions, though these are often easier to code.

The key to avoiding a deadlock is never to queue for a second lock while holding a lock. So, for three files, use something like:-

```
while true
do  flock -x a flock -nE 101 -s b flock -nE 102 c Command
    case $? in
    101) flock -s b;;
    102) flock -s c;;
    *)   break;;
done
```

The return values used in `flock -E` must be values which are never returned by the command, and when one of these values is returned, the script queues for the locked resource, then repeats the original call.

In principle it does not matter in which order the locks are requested, but it may simplify coding to request the exclusive lock first.

There is a more efficient solution which avoids releasing the queued lock immediately before requesting it again: build the run string each time, rebuilding it on each non-blocking failure, eg for the 101 return the run string would become:

```
flock -s b flock -nE 102 flock -nE 100 -x a c Command
```

(Obviously, an extra case for `100)` will be needed.)

In a more general case, the lock files would be passed to a function which saves the files in an array and builds the run string (the succession of `flock`s) and uses parameter arithmetic to select the file to queue on when the non-blocking locks fail.

The coding for both of these will be complex, especially when allowing for embedded spaces in `Command` and its parameters, so I have chosen the simple case above to illustrate the principle, which would be lost in the advanced coding for the general case.

Comment: Relating this to the diners, the algorithm is to pick up the left fork if it's available; otherwise, wait for it. If the right fork is also available, pick it up and eat; if not, put down the left fork again and wait for the right. With diners there could be a race condition where everyone picks up the left fork at _exactly_ the same time. In computing, this can't happen as only one thing can happen at each instant (this does not apply on a multi-computer network, but is true on a multi-core CPU, unless the background tasks are explicitly assigned to different cores).